# Modifying Section Frame

Tags: beamer, sectioning, beamer-metropolis

I'm doing a beamer. Each section creates a frame with its title. Is it possible to add text on this frame ?

For example adding "Thank you for your attention" on the `\section{Conclusion}` frame :)

Thank you !

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} 

\begin{document}
    \section{A}
    \section{B}
    \section{Conclusion} %here it creates a frame with "Conclusion" written on it, how to add text on this same frame ?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Your code does not compile, it causes and arithmetic overflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could temporarily add some text to the definition of the section page:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

{
  \addtobeamertemplate{section page}{}{%
    \centering
    \vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{minipage}{0.7875\linewidth}
      \raggedright
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
      \usebeamerfont{section title}
      text
    \end{minipage}\par
  }
  \section{Conclusion} %here it creates a frame with "Conclusion" written on it, how to add text on this same frame ?
}    

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! What if I want just one section page to disappear and not all of them ?

Comment: @Pierre I made all my changes inside a group (`{...}`). This does not affect other section pages.