# Footnote in a section title in Beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, footnotes, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to have a footnote to explain a joke (it's so bad that it needs to be explained) in the title of a section in a Beamer presentation with the Metropolis theme. The obvious thing to do works but the footnote is in the middle of the page.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\title{Ecuaciones recursivas}
\begin{document}
\section{¡El bottom\footnote{En inglés culo se dice bottom.} del mundo!}

\begin{frame}{Introduciendo parcialidad explícitamente}
  \begin{block}{De $\mathbb{Z} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{Z}$ a $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_\bot$}
    Lo que vamos a hacer es totalizar las funciones parciales
    agregando un nuevo elemento, $\bot$ que llamamos \emph{bottom}, al
    codominio.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps I should change the section page as indicated in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436081/38187).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `frame` option for the footnote to put it at the bottom of the frame instead of the end of the minipage which is around the section title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\title{Ecuaciones recursivas}
\begin{document}
\section{¡El bottom\footnote[frame]{En inglés culo se dice bottom.} del mundo!}

\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]